# How can I send an object as part of the JSON Web Token?

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

I'm trying to create a web token using the jjwt library, but I can't figure out how to send an object as one of the claims.  If I parse the object or manually create the string the entire string is coming through as the value instead of a separate JSON object.  For instance, I want to send something that looks like this:

```
{
    "iss": "NQoFK1NLVelFWOBQtQ8A",
    "iat": 1511963669,
    "user": {
        "id": "exampleuser",
        "email": "example@mail.com",
        "name": "A User",
    }
}
```

But all I've been able to create is:

```
{
    "iss": "NQoFK1NLVelFWOBQtQ8A",
    "iat": 1511963669,
    "user": "{\"id\": \"example@mail.com\",\"email\": \"example@mail.com\",\"name\": \"A User\"}"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This feature will be natively supported by JJWT when using Jackson in the upcoming JJWT 0.11.0 release (and you can read the [docs for this feature](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/tree/README-0-11-0#parsing-of-custom-claim-types) too).  But it is not available natively in 0.10.X and earlier.

Prior to 0.11.0, and assuming you're using Jackson, you'll have to do this yourself manually with the ObjectMapper:

```java
// when creating:
User user = getUser();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // or use an existing one
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
byte[] bytes = json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
String base64 = Encoders.BASE64.encode(bytes);
String jws = Jwts.builder()
  ...
  .claim("userJsonBase64", base64)
  ...
  .compact();

//when parsing:
String userJsonBase64 = Jwts.parser()....parseClaimsJws(jws).getBody().get("userJsonBase64", String.class);
bytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(userJsonBase64);
json = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
user = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answer, that will be a nice feature to have, once it's available.  I wanted to follow up and post a workaround that I found, in case it helps anyone else in the meantime.  I was able to create the JSON I needed using a Java HashMap (I found out the hard way that a Scala Map does not work) and then passing that as the value of the claim:

```
val user: util.Map[String, String] = new util.HashMap[String,
String]() user.put("id", email.value) user.put("email", email.value)
user.put("name", name.displayName)
```

...

```
val jws: String = Jwts.builder()
.claim("user", user)
.signWith(key).compact()
```